Is WSClock or a variant used in any Linux distribution?
I’ve been researching page replacement algorithms and came across WSClock, which combines the Clock algorithm with working set principles.
Now I have the following questions:

Is WSClock implemented in any Linux distribution, or does it exist as part of a specific kernel version?
If not WSClock specifically, are there any algorithms in Linux memory management that are inspired by or similar to WSClock in concept?

